# Adding ellipses to PCA (rda from vegan package) with ggplot2

Tags: r, ggplot2, pca, vegan

I performed a PCA with the rda function from the vegan package and I would like to add ellipses according to the three species that there are in my dataset.

Here what I've done:

```
mydatapca <- mydata[c(18:54)]
pca <- vegan::rda(mydatapca, scale = FALSE)
PCAvect <- scores(pca, display = "species", choices = c(1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7)) %>% as.data.frame()
PCAscores <- scores(pca, display = "sites", choices = c(1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7)) %>%
  as.data.frame() %>%
  rownames_to_column("site")
plot_PCA <- ggplot() +
  geom_point(data = PCAscores, aes(x = PC1, y = PC2, color = mydata$Species)) +
  scale_color_manual(name = "Species", values = pal) +
  geom_vline(xintercept = c(0), color = "grey70", linetype = 2) +
  geom_hline(yintercept = c(0), color = "grey70", linetype = 2) +
  clean_background +
  labs(x = "PC1 (42.74%)", y = "PC2 (19.63%)", title = "Principal Components Analysis")
plot_PCA
```

I tried adding stat_ellipses() but it doesn't work. Do you have any idea?

Here the output from dput(mydata)

```
mydata <- structure(list(Samples = c("s1", "s2", "s3", "s4", "s5", "s6", 
"s7", "s8", "s9", "s10", "s11", "s12", "s13", "s14", "s15", "s16", 
"s17", "s18", "s19", "s20", "s21", "s22", "s23", "s24"), Period = c("EarlySummer", 
"EarlySummer", "EarlySummer", "EarlySummer", "EarlySummer", "EarlySummer", 
"EarlySummer", "EarlySummer", "EarlySummer", "EarlySummer", "EarlySummer", 
"EarlySummer", "EarlySummer", "EarlySummer", "EarlySummer", "EarlySummer", 
"EarlySummer", "EarlySummer", "EarlySummer", "EarlySummer", "LateSummer", 
"LateSummer", "LateSummer", "LateSummer"), Date = c("18/06/2020", 
"18/06/2020", "18/06/2020", "18/06/2020", "18/06/2020", "19/06/2020", 
"19/06/2020", "19/06/2020", "19/06/2020", "19/06/2020", "19/06/2020", 
"03/07/2020", "03/07/2020", "08/07/2020", "08/07/2020", "08/07/2020", 
"08/07/2020", "09/07/2020", "09/07/2020", "09/07/2020", "03/09/2020", 
"03/09/2020", "03/09/2020", "10/09/2020"), SpeciesNumber = c(1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L), Sex = c("I", "I", "I", "I", "I", 
"I", "I", "F", "I", "I", "I", "I", "I", "F", "F", "F", "F", "I", 
"I", "I", "I", "I", "I", "F"), Species = c("sp1", "sp1", "sp1", 
"sp1", "sp1", "sp2", "sp2", "sp2", "sp2", "sp2", "sp3", "sp3", 
"sp3", "sp3", "sp3", "sp1", "sp1", "sp1", "sp2", "sp2", "sp1", 
"sp3", "sp3", "sp3"), Plant1 = c(0, 0, 0, 0.002380213, 0, 0.000103885, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0.000101595, 0, 0, 0, 
0), Plant2 = c(0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L), Plant3 = c(0.011303536, 
0, 0.002051703, 0.003001138, 0.015835956, 0, 0.000103381, 0.000306341, 
0.000100492, 0.016658202, 0.02392296, 0.020050378, 0, 0, 0, 0.000312077, 
0.003093993, 0, 0.000102501, 0.000101595, 0.005682971, 0, 0, 
0.000102459), Plant4 = c(0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0.000103381, 0, 0, 
0, 0, 0.000100756, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0.008503227, 
0), Plant5 = c(0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L), Plant6 = c(0.001762937, 
0, 0, 0.005174376, 0, 0.001142738, 0, 0, 0, 0.005688167, 0, 0, 
0, 0.000102135, 0.00020555, 0, 0, 0.006798517, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
0), Plant7 = c(0.004251789, 0, 0.001743947, 0.006623202, 0, 0, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0.000100756, 0.000708215, 0, 0.011613566, 0.105378134, 
0, 0.000103008, 0.003792538, 0, 0.000101482, 0, 0, 0.000204918
), Plant8 = c(0, 0, 0.000102585, 0.031667184, 0.288600142, 0.000311656, 
0.000516903, 0.151843153, 0.000904432, 0.000101574, 0.000304105, 
0.000503778, 0.000303521, 0.000714942, 0.000102775, 0.000104026, 
0, 0, 0.000615006, 0.002438281, 0.63618835, 0, 0.123450466, 0.000102459
), Plant9 = c(0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L), Plant10 = c(0L, 
0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L), Plant11 = c(0.001555533, 0.015557127, 
0.001538777, 0, 0, 0, 0.002377753, 0.004288778, 0.000703447, 
0.00761808, 0, 0.081511335, 0.000910563, 0.008579308, 0.124665982, 
0.020389056, 0.029339592, 0.012978986, 0.004715047, 0.010565884, 
0.028719302, 0, 0.047638562, 0.001946721), Plant12 = c(0, 0, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
0.000102459), Plant13 = c(0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
0, 0.000102135, 0, 0.000104026, 0.000213379, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
0), Plant14 = c(0.008088769, 0, 0.005744768, 0, 0, 0.022646998, 
0.006823116, 0.009292352, 0.003617727, 0.017775521, 0.017334009, 
0.0302267, 0.002124646, 0.001429885, 0, 0.0032248, 0, 0.006592501, 
0.002255023, 0.005892512, 0, 0.00212917, 0.001024485, 0.000922131
), Plant15 = c(0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L), Plant16 = c(0.104013274, 
0, 0.008309397, 0.051019352, 0.010151254, 0.033554955, 0.055411971, 
0.04350046, 0.00623053, 0.000304723, 0.025544856, 0.492594458, 
0.018110077, 0.070268614, 0.149434738, 0.106314366, 0.523845087, 
0.03461063, 0.0300328, 0.016052017, 0.01928151, 0.067525094, 
0.209507223, 0.391598361), Plant17 = c(0.004977704, 0.279523184, 
0.008924908, 0.088585325, 0.010658816, 0.037087056, 0.134808229, 
0.241703257, 0.145312029, 0.073743017, 0.047237709, 0.089672544, 
0.011938486, 0.098355633, 0.022302158, 0.147716634, 0.220740425, 
0.006798517, 0.002152522, 0.002539876, 0.114775726, 0.489202068, 
0.406105932, 0.506352459), Plant18 = c(0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
0L, 0L), Plant19 = c(0.003525874, 0, 0.000718096, 0.119321122, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0.000100492, 0.037785678, 0, 0, 0, 0.002859769, 0, 
0, 0.061773178, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0.000102459), Plant20 = c(0, 
0, 0, 0, 0.000101513, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0.000106689, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0.000204897, 0.000102459), Plant21 = c(0, 0, 0, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0.000102449, 
0), Plant22 = c(0.132635072, 0.00010102, 0.708247846, 0.005070889, 
0.125469495, 0.591211303, 0.454254109, 0.324006944, 0.83338358, 
0.020822753, 0.336137861, 0.055012594, 0.910157831, 0.247778572, 
0.058273381, 0.261312806, 0.009495359, 0.129686856, 0.033927839, 
0.065528802, 0.018469657, 0.008415289, 0.016289315, 0.024795082
), Plant23 = c(0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0.000415541, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
0, 0, 0.000102775, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0), Plant24 = c(0.000103702, 
0, 0.002462043, 0, 0, 0.01018076, 0.002687894, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
0, 0.020222653, 0, 0.010818683, 0, 0.003193243, 0.003792538, 
0.002946256, 0, 0.003548616, 0.012191374, 0.000819672), Plant25 = c(0, 
0, 0, 0.005795302, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0.002042692, 0, 
0, 0.002773925, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0), Plant26 = c(0L, 0L, 0L, 
0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L), Plant27 = c(0.000103702, 0, 0.000512926, 
0.000103488, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0.000100492, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0.000204269, 
0, 0.001144284, 0.018777339, 0, 0.000102501, 0, 0.004465192, 
0.00527223, 0.002868559, 0.001434426), Plant28 = c(0.167790107, 
0.023941812, 0.008309397, 0.256028149, 0.011470917, 0.146997715, 
0.159516179, 0.000204228, 0.000301477, 0.043880142, 0, 0.083324937, 
0.019526507, 0.352772955, 0.525282631, 0.065952356, 0.04651659, 
0.094767202, 0.006355064, 0.011378645, 0.000304445, 0.000101389, 
0.01106444, 0.001434426), Plant29 = c(0, 0, 0, 0.000103488, 0, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0.000106689, 0, 0.001947519, 
0.001117545, 0, 0, 0, 0), Plant30 = c(0, 0.02303263, 0.095609356, 
0.022663769, 0, 0.009869105, 0.004135222, 0.022771367, 0.001004924, 
0.028643982, 0.01530664, 0, 0.010117361, 0.001123481, 0.008324769, 
0.008530115, 0.001707031, 0.004429337, 0.003485035, 0.005079752, 
0.001623706, 0, 0, 0.002663934), Plant31 = c(0, 0, 0.003487895, 
0, 0, 0.000103885, 0.000103381, 0.005309915, 0, 0, 0, 0.000201511, 
0.000910563, 0.160964151, 0, 0, 0.010348874, 0.059950556, 0.780135301, 
0.786548816, 0.000101482, 0, 0, 0), Plant32 = c(0.23685575, 0.544196383, 
0.143311449, 0.275897754, 0.376713024, 0.061500104, 0.133360901, 
0.180639232, 0.007034469, 0.391163027, 0.520831221, 0.093803526, 
0.019627681, 0.012868961, 0.044501542, 0.047851867, 0.043422597, 
0.04697157, 0.039667897, 0.051102306, 0.108991273, 0.389536652, 
0.107570946, 0.026127049), Plant33 = c(0.319298973, 0.113647843, 
0.008822323, 0.118907172, 0.112475891, 0.084043216, 0.037216996, 
0.016133973, 0.001205909, 0.355815135, 0.01327927, 0.021360202, 
0.005564549, 0.019303442, 0.055087359, 0.22084677, 0.023578363, 
0.593119077, 0.086818368, 0.03647262, 0.049015628, 0.034269492, 
0.053478127, 0.041188525), Plant34 = c(0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0.008580585, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0), Plant35 = c(0, 
0, 0, 0, 0.010354279, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0.000101368, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0.011264461, 0, 0, 0), Plant36 = c(0.003733278, 
0, 0.000102585, 0.007658077, 0.038168714, 0.000831082, 0, 0, 
0, 0, 0, 0.031536524, 0, 0.000306404, 0.000102775, 0, 0.004160888, 
0, 0, 0.002133496, 0.001014816, 0, 0, 0), Plant37 = c(0, 0, 0, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0.000102501, 0, 
0, 0, 0, 0), Observed = c(15L, 7L, 17L, 17L, 11L, 15L, 15L, 12L, 
13L, 13L, 10L, 14L, 12L, 18L, 13L, 15L, 17L, 13L, 17L, 16L, 15L, 
9L, 14L, 17L)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -24L))
```

Comment: Hi @Angy, could you please share your data using `dput(mydata)`? So we can help you better.

Comment: I'm afraid I can't, it is a very big file and I cannot share it on the web. Is there another way to do it? Thank you

Comment: Is it ok if I made a subset of mydata and I share here the dput(mydata) in this way?

Comment: A subset of your data is also good, you could use for example `head(dput(mydata), 20)`.

Comment: Done! Sorry for the format, I'm new here and it is still not clear to me how to put the code!

Answer (score 0):

One option would be `geforce:: geom_mark_ellipse`:

```r
mydatapca <- mydata[grepl("^Plant", names(mydata))]

library(vegan)
#> Loading required package: permute
#> Loading required package: lattice
#> This is vegan 2.5-7
library(ggplot2)
library(tibble)
library(dplyr)

pca <- vegan::rda(mydatapca, scale = FALSE)
PCAvect <- scores(pca, display = "species", choices = c(1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7)) %>% as.data.frame()
PCAscores <- scores(pca, display = "sites", choices = c(1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7)) %>%
  as.data.frame() %>%
  rownames_to_column("site") %>%
  bind_cols(Species = mydata$Species)

ggplot(data = PCAscores, aes(x = PC1, y = PC2, color = Species)) +
  geom_point() +
  ggforce::geom_mark_ellipse() +
  #scale_color_manual(name = "Species", values = pal) +
  geom_vline(xintercept = c(0), color = "grey70", linetype = 2) +
  geom_hline(yintercept = c(0), color = "grey70", linetype = 2) +
  #clean_background +
  labs(x = "PC1 (42.74%)", y = "PC2 (19.63%)", title = "Principal Components Analysis")
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you, but it doesn't work for me. I changed the variables names in the subset of my data, so Plant1, Plant2 ecc are actually the scientific names of each plant. Maybe it is for this that it doesn't work